# Adding a VF page to setup area

Tags: visualforce, setup

As we all know, setup area contains all links in sidebar and shows relevant content in right side when we click on a link in left side. I want to add my link to left sidebar. Can I do that? Any thoughts?
[image]

Comment: Can you please add screen shot to make it crystal clear?

Comment: I have added. Please see

Comment: Why do you want specially on set up ?Like cant it be on home page component.Also homepage component you can adjust for various profiles?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a way to add a menu item to the setup menu.

However you can activate the setup menu so that when someone navigates to the VF page, the user *appears* to be working in the setup menu:

```
<apex:page setup="true" ... >
...
</apex:page>
```

Using this, you remove the standard SFDC sidebar from the VF page.